# Post XML request and XML response Volley Library

Tags: android, xml, wcf, post, android-volley

I have already integrated volley library working good with JSON. Now am trying to access WCF SOAP I do not know how to pass XML string as request and how to get XML string as response.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String  tag_string_req = "string_req";

    //String url = "URL......";



    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            pDialog.hide();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/xml; charset=" +
                    getParamsEncoding();
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            String postData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                    "<sampletag>\n" +
                    "\t<sampletag>data</sampletag>\n" +
                    "</sampletag>"; // TODO get your final output
            try {
                return postData == null ? null :
                        postData.getBytes(getParamsEncoding());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                // TODO consider if some other action should be taken
                return null;
            }
        }
        };
```

// Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String request of Volley. The String request returns a string which can you parse using [XMLReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html)

```
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
new Response.Listener<String>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        processDataUsingXMLReader(reponse);
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                                
     // handle error response
   }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Volley` does not have any XML Request, checkout the official documentation: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/android-4.3_r0.9/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/

There are two ways you can do it:

> Method 1

So, you will have to fetch the raw String using `StringRequest` and then parse it.

Code:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
    new Response.Listener<String>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
          // now, convert response (String) to XML 
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() 
    {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                                
          //error
       }
    }
);
queue.add(request);
```

To convert `String` to `XML`:
You can try `Simple-XML`, it is a XML Marshaling Tool. Link : http://simple.sourceforge.net/download.php

Sample code (string to xml using `Simple`) :

```
 Serializer serializer = new Persister();
 serializer.read(Pojo.class, response);
```

> Method 2

Try this Volley Adapter Class : https://gist.github.com/itsalif/6149365
It also does the same, using Simple-XML to serialize XML Objects without your coding effort.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to parse XML data using Android Volley from the String response, you can achieve this by converting the response to an InputStream using ByteArrayInputStream, as follows:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser();
            InputStream inputStream = new 
            ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            List<YourObject> object = new ArrayList<>();
            object.addAll(xmlParser.parseFeed(inputStream));
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                             
        }
    }
);
```

This example simply demonstrates parsing an RSS feed and storing an array of objects in a List, which is demonstrated in greater detail [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).