# How to post body of the xml data in android web service?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-volley

i am trying to post request with xml body to the web service using volley api,but it returns output like invalid credentials.below is my code

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                Log.e("onResponse","...."+s);
            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.e("onErrorResponse","...."+volleyError);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/xml; charset=" +
                        getParamsEncoding();
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("SLUsername", "uname");
                params.put("SLPassword", "pwd");
                params.put("CurrentDate", "date");
                return params;
            }


        };



// Schedule the request on the queue
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

below is my sample xml body

```
<GetDetails>
<SLUsername>Settings Username</SLUsername>
<SLPassword>Settings Password</SLPassword>
<CurrentDate>Settings Date</CurrentDate>
</GetDetails>
```

How to send this xml body to the api?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203585/3505534 have a look in to this

Comment: @TheCodeStar hi thanks for reply,i didn't understand that code,where is passing body to the service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post XML request and XML response Volley Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678487/post-xml-request-and-xml-response-volley-library)

Comment: @TominB how it is duplicate?can you explain me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43679077/8117793 Read every entries in answer. and Volley Documentation. Volley doesnot have xml request methodolagy